Confusions regarding empty matrix in MATLAB?
I am trying to implement a code in a MATLAB and system is pure/ideal integrator and system has no zero
I have two confusions,
1)Why i am getting two different types of output for an empty matrix?
Variable z1 (which is in 2nd last code line) has 1x1 cell array {0x1 double}
and
Variable z2 (which is in last code line) has value
Empty matrix: 0-by-1
2)According to my understanding, both these outputs are exactly equal(both are empty matrix) but why MATLAB is considering this matrix is having zero row and 1 column, but i don't see any row or any column
My code:
clc;clear;close all
C=0.1e-6
R=47e3
num=1
den=[-R*C 0]
sys=tf(num,den)
[z1,p1,k]=zpkdata(sys)
[p2,z2]=pzmap(sys)


See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-arrays.html

Are you sure you get z1 as "[0x1 double]" and not 1x1 cell array {0x1 double}?

@LuisMendo yes you are right, we get 1 x 1 cell array {0 x 1 double }

The difference is that one function returns a cell array of arrays, and the other function just returns an array. A cell array is a container which can hold different objects in each cell, and critically a cell can be an array.
In this case, the outputs z1 and z2 are NOT the same. The output z1 is a cell array whose first element is an array of doubles. The output z2 is an array of doubles.
Of note is that any array that has at least one dimension of size 0 is considered an empty array (see isempty).
Behavior Examples
The following examples may be helpful in understanding the types of these variables.
>> a = zeros(0, 1)

a =

  0×1 empty double column vector

>> whos("a")
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         0x1                 0  double   

This is to be expected, an empty array should have no data. Now, this is a bit of lie from MATLAB, since the size and type data is stored somewhere to display it to us, but we will ignore that for now.
>> b = {a}

b =

  1×1 cell array

    {0×1 double}

>> whos("b")
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  b         1x1               104  cell      

Notice even though we are just storing an empty array, we are using 104 (!) bytes. All of this data is that size and type data of the array we are storing, along with a pointer to the actual data.
Note: since an empty array stores no data, the pointer is most likely a null pointer.
We can extract the array from a cell with curly brace indexing:
>> c = b{1}

c =

  0×1 empty double column vector

>> whos("c")
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  c         0x1                 0  double  

Again, we have an empty array of size "zero".
>> b{2} = zeros(0, 1)

b =

  1×2 cell array

    {0×1 double}    {0×1 double}

>> whos("b")
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  b         1x2               208  cell  

With two elements, we now have to store information about two different arrays. Each cell requires 104 bytes, so two cells requires 208 bytes.
Now, let's store some actual data, and also use the fact that a cell array can store different types.
>> b{2} = ["Hello", ", ", "World!"]

b =

  1×2 cell array

    {0×1 double}    {1×3 string}

>> whos("b")
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  b         1x2               476  cell    

>> d = ["Hello", ", ", "World!"]

d = 

  1×3 string array

    "Hello"    ", "    "World!"

>> whos("d")
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  d         1x3               268  string   

Note the size of b is precisely the size of two cells + the size of each array or 2 * 104 + 0 + 268 = 476
Implementation Example
It may help to consider a simple example what is happening under the hood here. Consider the following pseudocode for how you might store an array:
class Array:
    type: double
    data_pointer: double*
    rows: unsigned int
    cols: unsigned int

Each array object has a field that has a pointer to a location on the heap, where the actual data is stored. It also has a size, which for this simple case we will assume to only support 2D arrays.
So the object z2 might look something like
>> z2
Array:
    type: double
    data_pointer: NULL
    rows: 0
    cols: 1

A cell array can be constructed by making an array of pointers
class CellArray:
    type: Array
    data_pointer: Array*
    rows: unsigned int
    cols: unsigned int

Then the object z1 might look like
>> z1
CellArray:
    type: Array
    data_pointer: 0xDEADBEEF
    rows: 1 // Not an empty cell array
    cols: 1

Clearly, these objects are not the same.
